# How can I see a list of DONE tasks in org-agenda sorted by closed date?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

My config (spacemacs with ~0 extra) sets a `CLOSED` time when I move a task in org-mode to `DONE`:

```
***** DONE A task
CLOSED: [2022-09-12 Mon 16:18] SCHEDULED: <2022-09-07 Wed>
```

It's easy to only show `DONE` tasks, but now I'd like to get an agenda view that can use the timestamp set for `CLOSED` so that I can look back at what items I've finished in the past week. What can I do to build this?

I'm a beginner at this so I'm probably missing some basics. For instance I don't know what the difference is between a `[timestamp]` and a `<timestamp>`.

Comment: For the difference between `[ts]` and `<ts>` see [Inactive timestamp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps).

Comment: Inactive timestamps (`[ts]`) do not contribute to the agenda, whereas active timestamps (`<ts>`) do.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was trying to do the same thing and ended cooking something up. So I might as well share.

Since there doesn't seem to be anything of the sort available out of the box, we need a custom sort function and thus also to set an entry in `org-agenda-custom-commands` so as to be able to set proper sorting. For an custom-commands entry like:

```lisp
("n" "Whatever"
 ((tags "CLOSED<=\"<now>\""))
 ((org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'org-cmp-closed)
  (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-down))))
```

We define the corresponding sort function as:

```lisp
(defun org-cmp-closed (a b)
  (let* ((a-marker (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
         (b-marker (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
         (now (current-time))
         (a-closed-ts (org-timestamp-from-string
                       (org-entry-get a-marker "CLOSED")))
         (b-closed-ts (org-timestamp-from-string
                       (org-entry-get b-marker "CLOSED")))
         (a-closed-time (or (and a-closed-ts
                                 (org-timestamp-to-time a-closed-ts))
                            now))
         (b-closed-time (or (and b-closed-ts
                                 (org-timestamp-to-time b-closed-ts))
                            now)))
    (cond ((time-less-p b-closed-time a-closed-time) +1)
          ((time-less-p a-closed-time b-closed-time) -1)
          (t nil))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the agenda dispatcher view (i.e. after `C-c a` if you have customized the setting as the manual suggests - or after `M-x org-agenda`), select `m` for a query to [match tags/properties/todo](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html) and specify the following entry:

```
TODO="DONE"&CLOSED>="<-1w>"
```

That should give you a list of `DONE` items that were `CLOSED` in the past week. I don't think it's sorted though and I don't remember how to sort that view (or even if it is possible). Untested.